# How can i make my token to persist after creating a new user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing an api with expressjs and mongodb.

The user can login. Only if the logged in user is an admin, then the user can access /register to register new users.

So i want that the only person able to create new employees and their respective user is the admin user, from inside the app.

I have the following methods in my controller auth.js:

```
exports.register = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password, name, lastName } = req.body;
        const user = await User.create({
            email,
            password
        });

        const employee = await Employee.create({
            name,
            lastName,
            user: user._id
        })

        res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          user: user,
          employee: employee
        })
    
});

// @desc   Loginuser
// @route  POST /api/v1/auth/login
// @access Public

exports.login = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
  
    // Validate emil & password
    if (!email || !password) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Please provide an email and password', 400));
    }
  
    // Check for user
    const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
  
    if (!user) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
    }
  
    // Check if password matches
    const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
  
    if (!isMatch) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid credentials', 401));
    }

    sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);

  });

// Get token from model, create cookie and send response
const sendTokenResponse = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    // Create token
    const token = user.getSignedJwtToken();
  
    const options = {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
      httpOnly: true
    };
  
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      options.secure = true;
    }
  
    res
      .status(statusCode)
      .cookie('token', token, options)
      .json({
        success: true,
        token
      });
  };

  // @desc   Get current logged in user
  // @route  POST /api/auth/me
  // @access Private

  exports.getMe = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: user
    });
  
  })
```

And i have the following middleware functions:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const asyncHandler = require('./async');
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');
const User = require('../models/User');

// Protect Routes 
exports.protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;
  
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } /* else if (req.cookies.token) {
        token = req.cookies.token;
    } */
  
    // Make sure token exists
    if (!token) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Not authorized to access this route', 401));
    }
  
    try {
      // Verify token
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  
      // Check if decoded has id property
      if (!decoded.id) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid token', 401));
      }
  
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
      if (!req.user) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse('User not found', 404));
      }
  
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorResponse('Invalid token', 401));
    }
  });
  


//Grant access to specific roles
exports.authorize = (...roles) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if(!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`User role ${req.user.role} is not authorized to access this route`, 403));
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

The log in works fine and i can get the current logged in user. And if the logged in user is not an admin i get the corresponding error message. If the user is an admin i am being able to create a new user. The issue is that after creating a new user, the token of the already logged in user is deleted, it is not persisting. And if i go again to the endpoint `api/auth/me` i get the error message of `Invalid token`.

How can i make my token to persist? Because maybe with the admin user i want to create more than one user without being logged out.

Comment: What i do not get is are you using cookies or an authorization header?

Comment: I am using both. @Balint

Comment: from the code exports.register = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password, name, lastName } = req.body;
        const user = await User.create({
            email,
            password
        });

        const employee = await Employee.create({
            name,
            lastName,
            user: user._id
        })

        res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          user: user,
          employee: employee
        })
    
}); you do not seems to return a new cookie or token in the body, are you calling a login somewhere?

Comment: @Balint i added this line to the register function:

`sendTokenResponse(req.user, 200, res);`

This generates me a new token for the already logged in user so that my login persists. But is not the same token as the first one. This works and i am able to create several users. But i don´t know if this will affect me later instead of persisting the first token when i log in.

Comment: I will show you an alternative implementation tomorrow

Comment: @Balint ok great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the token is deleted because you don't resend the token in the response of register function.

If you add `sendTokenResponse(req.user, 200, res);` to  register section, you'll create a new token.

You can use existing token in below code. For your case your code should be like,

```
exports.register = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
        /* 
         * Check the session
         * If there is a session and logged in user is an admin
         * OR
         * If you already have access the token, skip this  
         * section and resend the token in response
         */
        const { token } = req.cookies;
        
        .
        .
        .

        // There should be two different responses here too
        // This is for logged in user as an admin
        res
         .status(200)
         .cookie('token', token, options)
         .json({
          success: true,
          user: user,
          employee: employee
        })

        // This is for non-session cases
        res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          user: user,
          employee: employee
        })
    
});
```

I told you how to do it, I hope you can code it :).

NOTE: I think instead of complicating the function that much, you should write a new function called addUser and give access to only admin and ofc you should resend the token in response.